# Populando um DataGridView Existente

Tags: c#, winforms

Galera estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um dataGrid,  no qual gostaria de inserir mais linhas no mesmo.
- Quando o registro é novo O Grid aceita normal, mas já quando vou editar o mesmo ele me reporta:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Não é possível adicionar linhas
>   programaticamente à coleção de linhas de DataGridView quando o
>   controle é associado a dados.'

Segue o código mostrando como está:

```
public void setDadosGrid (int id, string descricao)
{      

    for (var i = 0; i <= dgvExames.SelectedRows.Count; i++)
    {

        {
            if (dgvExames.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                dgvExames.Columns.Add("Id", "Id");
                dgvExames.Columns.Add("Descricao", "Descricao");
            }

            dgvExames.Rows.Add(id,descricao);
            i++;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Você está associando o seu DataGridView com alguma fonte de dados (DataSource, DataTable)?

Comment: Se o DataGrid está conectado a uma fonte de dados, você não vai conseguir adicionar manualmente linhas a ele dessa forma. Tente o seguinte: `var row = dgvExames.DataSource.NewRow();  row.Columns["Id"] = id; .... dgvExames.DataSource.Add(row);` Me diga se funcionou, pode ser preciso fazer o cast no DataSource, ai posto uma resposta mais detalhada

Comment: @RicardoPontual cara vlw mesmo pela dica funcionou perfeitamente, situações que passamos despercebidos diante desse problema. mas muito obrigado.